# Could not load file or assembly 'applicationname' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

We made a  .net application which ran smoothly but when we tried to execute the .exe on another machine encountered the error

> The application was unable to start correctly(oxcOOOOO7b)

We tried to rebuild the solution in visual studio 2010 but encountered the error:

> Could not load file or assembly '*crawler*' or one of its dependencies.
>   The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

What could be the reason? Could this be because of absence of .net framework 3.5? We have .net framework 4.0 and 3.0 installed on Windows 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while trying to run project:The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135925/error-while-trying-to-run-projectthe-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly)

Answer (score 0):

> It is a low-level assembly loading problem. The CLR has located a file
>   with the right name but when it tries to load the assembly, it finds
>   out that the file doesn't contain a proper manifest. A .NET assembly
>   must contain a manifest, it contains metadata that describes the
>   assembly, listing the types in the assembly, etc.

I did some investigation and found these solutions that might help.

1. Make sure that 2 .exe/dlls have same name.
2. Make sure that whatever is your target .NET framework, it is
   installed on your machine.
3. Target .NET framework 4 instead of .NET framework 4 client profile.
4. Check to see if all the build options are set to either x86 or x64,
   depending on your system architecture, or AnyCPU.
5. It may be because of some virus. Try to scan your machine with an anti virus and re-build the project.

For more details [refer this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135925/error-while-trying-to-run-projectthe-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly).