# Error while trying to run project:The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I try to run the project it says:

> Error while trying to run project:could not load file or assembly '*Project.exe*' or one of its dependencies.
> The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

When I ran the exe from the debug folder I got this error:

> application unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

I also reinstalled Visual Studio but it doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

It is a low-level assembly loading problem.  The CLR has located a file with the right name but when it tries to load the assembly, it finds out that the file doesn't contain a proper manifest.  A .NET assembly must contain a manifest, it contains metadata that describes the assembly, listing the types in the assembly, etc.

If you have no clue what EXE or DLL might be the troublemaker then you can use the [Fuslogvw.exe utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

1. Start it from the "Visual Studio Command Prompt".
2. Click the "Settings" button and click the "Log binding failures to disk" radio button.
3. Switch back to VS and start the program and wait for the exception to occur.
4. Back to Fuslogvw, click the "Refresh" button and double-click the added entry.
5. It shows you the file it found.

Several possibilities, a common one these days is to trying to load a .NET 4 assembly with an EXE that asked for CLR version 2.  That requires an app.exe.config file that forces CLR 4 to be used.

Comment: "trying to load a .NET 4 assembly with an EXE that asked for CLR version 2. That requires an app.exe.config file that forces CLR 4 to be used." - This was my problem

Comment: As a side note, if the radio buttons Hans is talking about are disabled, you'd have to run `Fuslogvw.exe` as Administrator

Answer (score 5):

In my case I just change Target Framework(.Net Framework 4) in Project Properties. It solves the problem.

Comment: I try this but not work for me,it's seems there is no solution for me:),i just must change windows

Comment: In my case Target Framework was ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile" after change it is .Net Framework 4. It solves the my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when I use Vs2012 utimate to publish Asp.net Mvc4, then upload dll to server.
I fixed it by build code as Release mode then upload all dll in bin folder to server.

Answer (score 0):

0xc000007b is "STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT". From experience, this points me to the project properties.
A few things worth checking out:

- Check to see if all the build options are set to either x86 or x64, depending on your system architecture, or AnyCPU.
- If you're using dlls, consider whether they were compiled for your target architecture or not. If not, then recompile them accordingly or get them in the right version from wherever you got them.
- Finally, check if your project assembly and loaded assemblies have different names. That seems to make things go boom as well.

Answer (score 0):

IN my case it get fixed by just going to project properties and set-->startup object projectname.program and build->platform target--> x86.

Answer (score 0):

i just resolve this by problem by restarting System as well in project properties i set to multi users as well in combo box start option.hope this will help u.