# "Assembly Manifest" error in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've been facing a problem recently with visual studio,

Every time i debug a program it says:

> "error while trying to run project: cold not load file
>
> or assembly 'console application1' or one of it's dependencies. the
>   module was expected to
>
> contain an assembly manifest."

even if the project is blank like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication4
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried to clean solution and reinstall vs2010 but nothing works.

Comment: Any of the things in this thread help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226676/the-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly-manifest

Comment: [This question][1] and [this question][2] seemed to have some possible solutions that may help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135925/error-while-trying-to-run-projectthe-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226676/the-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly-manifest?rq=1

Comment: I would recommend a different title since "Hard proplem to solve in visual studio" doesn't say anything.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: @CailinP sorry callin but i wasn't able to solve it i just knew what was the proplem from fuslogvw report

Answer (score 1):

The error "The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest" usually refers to a low level assembly loading issue. The Common Language Runtime has found a file with the correct name, but when the assembly is attempted to be loaded it doesn't contain the right manifest (which has information pertaining to the assembly).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135925/error-while-trying-to-run-projectthe-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly) contains information on how to test and resolve this issue.