# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows

I am developing a windows application in visual studio 2012 ultimate. But I am getting following error when I am running it:

> Error: while trying to run your project, could not load file or assembly `WindowsApplication1` or one of it's dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Comment: Did you move something, or accidently delete something in your WindowsApplication1 file?

Comment: no..just dragged a button and clikced on run but getting error,and selected build project but getting error,and created new project but still getting the same error

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135925/error-while-trying-to-run-projectthe-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.It was just because of file missing from my windows os.So just formatted and installed new OS and then installed Visual Studio.Now working fine...